# Domain of $A^{1/2}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{T}^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $A$ be a densely defined unbounded self-adjoint operator defined on $L^2(\mathbb{T}^2)$, where $\mathbb{T}^2$ stands for the 2-torus. It is known that $A$ is positive, that is, $\langle Au, u\rangle \geq 0, u \in L^2(\mathbb{T}^2)$. It is also known that $\mathcal{D}(A) \subset H^1(\mathbb{T}^2)$. Let $A^{1/2}$ denote the square root of $A$, defined by the spectral theorem, which says that apriori, $A^{1/2}$ is a densely defined self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb{T}^2)$. But can we say something more, like, $\mathcal{D}(A^{1/2}) \subset H^{1/2}(\mathbb{T}^2)$? Thanks!

Comment: What if $A=(-\Delta)^{1/4}$ for example?

Comment: @Jose27 Oops, forgot a key assumption. Thanks for pointing it out, I have edited the question properly now.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can look up a related matter in the Kato conjecture.